# How can I let Flipclock automatically set time from a specific date

Tags: javascript, css, flipclock

So I've set up Flipclock, it's working but it's not working as I want it to

This is the code:

```
endtimeYear: 0,
        endtimeMonth: 0,
        endtimeDate: 0,
        endtimeHours: 0,
        endtimeMinutes: 0,
        endtimeSeconds: 0,
```

I'm trying to set up a countdown, but everytime I put in the date, hours, minutes and seconds it doesn't update automatically. If I example edit my code, it'll just reset, which it ain't supposed to do.

If I example set it to October 1st, it should automatically just go after that.

Anyone knows how to do this? Sorry, I'm having a hard time trying to explain the problem. Hope you understands!

Answer (score 1):

Since [FlipClock.js](http://flipclockjs.com/) takes the number of seconds as a parameter, take the date that you want the countdown to end on `new Date('October 1 2019)` and subtract that from the current date `new Date()`. From their example of [different clock faces](http://flipclockjs.com/faces/daily-counter) include the `clockFace: 'DailyCounter'` option as well as `showSeconds: false` to make it more clean.

```js
const seconds = (new Date('October 1 2019').getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000
if (seconds > 0) {
  new FlipClock($('.your-clock'), seconds, {
    countdown: true,
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    showSeconds: false
  });
} else { 
  $('.your-clock').text("It's October 1st!");
}
```

```html
<br/>
<div class="your-clock"></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
```